# Parse .txt file to populate html select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a text file organized in JSON format that looks like this:

```html
{
    "courseSubject": "Accountancy",
    "courseSubject": "American Studies",
    "courseSubject": "Anatomy & Regenerative Biology",
    "courseSubject": "Anesthesiology",
    "courseSubject": "Anthropology",
    "courseSubject": "Applied Science",
    "courseSubject": "Arabic",
    "courseSubject": "Art/Art History"
}
```

I am trying to parse through my text file and add the JSON value to my html select dropdown. Please see my code below, I do not know where I'm going wrong:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-inverse" data-width="300px">
  
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

 $.getJSON("courses.txt", function( json ) {
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
    $('.selectpicker').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + json[key] + '</option>');
});

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, I want my select options to be: 
Accountancy
American Studies,
Anatomy & Regenerative Biology etc...

Comment: Class selectors must be preceded by a dot, eg `$('.selectpicker')`. Plus, be aware that your solution will cause every `option` to have the same value key.

Comment: I suggest to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: @LcSalazar my code isn't populating my select with anything. I don't know what I am misssing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add dot (`.`) before `$('selectpicker')` because you're using class selector, it should be :

```
$('.selectpicker').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + json[val] + '</option>');
___^
```

In the both `for` loop and `each` function.

```js
var json = {
    "courseSubject": "Accountancy",
    "courseSubject": "American Studies",
    "courseSubject": "Anatomy & Regenerative Biology",
    "courseSubject": "Anesthesiology",
    "courseSubject": "Anthropology",
    "courseSubject": "Applied Science",
    "courseSubject": "Arabic",
    "courseSubject": "Art/Art History"
};

$.each(json, function(key, value) {
    $('.selectpicker').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + json[key] + '</option>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-inverse" data-width="300px"></select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made the edits above. My select is still not populating

Comment: hmm seems to only be picking up the last element in the array.

Comment: That because you have the same `key`, already mentioned in question comments _Plus, be aware that your solution will cause every option to have the same value key_. but it will work gracefully just if you change the keys.